# Failed Image Build with DockerHub

Tags: dockerhub

Even though the last message in the DockerHub log:

```
Successfully built 73dfc9054b7e
```

DockerHub states that the status is 'Build Error'. The image builds correctly on multiple local machines, and the last message from the log has no errors. What could be the reason for the build error? Does anyone know if there is there another place besides the DockerHub log where we can see why the build was not successful?

Docker seems to be very promising but these types of errors make us hesitate when thinking about migrating some of our nodes to docker containers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did search your issue through the build id, and tried reproducing the bug. You might have seen me forking your public GitHub branch. We found and resolved the issue. 
If you see the latest build for `anaconda-plus`, it succeeded.
If you encounter such issue again, please create a [support ticket](https://support.docker.com/hc/en-us?flash_digest=8bd4b59e11d8c9b50dbf02e9cae4f7ab52b57878).